# Three rendering with boilerplate

Tags: three.js

Why do I have an order to render a [screenshot de mon render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUqrR.png)? (Meaning: What is my mistake? I know that Three.js imports meshes into the scene successively, but how can I do it simultaneously, like Bruno does on the screen? [Screen shot de la ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejcKF.jpg))"

I imagine a way to implement a group object in Power; maybe the issue comes from this:

```
export default class {
  House = {};

  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this.HouseGroup = new Group();

    this.House.floor = new Floor();
    this.House.walls = new walls(0, 1, 0);
    this.House.roof = new Roof(0, 3, 0);

    Object.keys(this.House).forEach((key) => {
      this.HouseGroup.add(this.House[key].mesh);
    });

    Common.scene.add(this.HouseGroup);
  }

  dispose() {}

  render(t) {
    Object.keys(this.House).forEach((key) => {
      this.House[key].render(t);
    });
  }
```

But I tried a new way to add meshes to the group that looks like this:

```
 this.HouseGroup.add(
      this.House.floor.mesh,
      this.House.walls.mesh,
      this.House.roof.mesh
    );
```

Still a failure, haha

Here's a repo of my project :

https://github.com/Stan2hssn/Three.js_journey/tree/haunted_house

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, your renderer ([Common.renderer](https://github.com/Stan2hssn/Three.js_journey/blob/haunted_house/graphics/Common.js#L36)) does not "test" depth (`depth: false`, actually not drawing on depth buffer to then test if shapes are overlapping), it's for optimisation that it is disabled, you should enable it to have depth sorting on common THREE materials.

In THREE with `Renderer.depth` enable, each object draws on the actual render but also on the z-buffer, then when you draw a new object it calculate with z-buffer which parts of the new object should drawn or not.
[image]

Comment: So it is a good practice to set ```depth: False``` ? 

Do you need to apply a depth params to each components ? Do I need to keep this  ```depth: False``` ?

Comment: It is only a lever of optimisation to disable it, if you need it (as it seems), you should enable it.